# finding an outside function given composite function

Tags: functions

I have trouble finding the rule of the 'outside' function, given the composite function and inside function, I think you have to use some sort of substitution but otherwise I have no clue.

Does anyone know the answer to the following question: 
If $p(x)= \frac{4}{\sqrt{3x-6}}$ and $ f(p(x)) = 3x-4$, find the rule of $f(x).$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Things become clearer if you introduce an auxiliary variable $y=p(x)$. So we have

$y=\frac{4}{\sqrt{3x-6}} \\ \Rightarrow 3y^2(x-2) = 16 \\ \Rightarrow x = \frac{16}{3y^2}+2 \\ \Rightarrow f(y) = 3x-4 = \frac{16}{y^2}+2$

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the inverse function of $p(x)$, so that $p(q(x))=x$.  Then replace $x$ in your problem with $q(x)$

Comment: Given the composite and the inner functions, is the outer function we find unique? I can think of $f(g(x))=2$ and $g(x)=4$ to have different potential outer functions such as $f(x)=x/2$ or $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, but does that always hold?

Comment: If $p(x)$ is not $1-1$ then $q(x)$ won't be unique

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answers of *gandalf61* and *Empy2* for anyone who might see this in the future.

We are aiming to find an expression for $f(x)$ in terms of the functions which are given or can be found relatively easily, that is, $f \circ p$, $\ p$ and $\ p^{-1}$.

$x = (p \circ p^{-1})(x)$

$\Rightarrow f(x) = f((p \circ p^{-1})(x))$

$\Rightarrow f(x) = (f \circ p)(p^{-1}(x))$

Since $f \circ (p \circ p^{-1}) = (f \circ p) \circ p^{-1}$

---

In the example OP gave, the inverse of $p(x)$ is

$p^{-1}(x) = \frac{16}{3x^2} + 2$

Therefore,

$f(x) = (f \circ p)(\frac{16}{3x^2} + 2)$

$\Rightarrow f(x) = 3(\frac{16}{3x^2} + 2) - 4$

$\Rightarrow f(x) = \frac{16}{x^2} + 2$